# How to add fonts in LibreOffice writer

Tags: 12.04, fonts

I want to add nepali fonts like kantipur in Ubuntu 12.04.How can I do this.

Answer (score 5):

You have first to install the Nepali font in order to use it. You can download the font [Here](http://www.nepali.info/nepali/fonts/fonts/nepali.zip).  Once downloaded open file manager.  For the Kantipur font you can download [Here](http://www.nepali.info/nepali/fonts/fonts/kantipur.zip), and just do the same for it.

For other Nepali fonts you can download [Here](http://www.nepali.info/nepali/fonts/).

[image]

When it opens, double click on the file, to open it.

[image]

Once it opens double click on the file Nepali.TTF, that will open the font viewer window

[image]

When it opens click on install to install the font.

[image]

Once installed, go ahead and open Libreoffice Writer, and change the font to the Nepali font as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you best answer . Now i got solution and feel too good ... Thank you so much