# installing another language fonts in Lubuntu

Tags: fonts

I want to type in another language(nepalese to be specific) in abiword or libre office in Lubuntu. I am new to linux so hoping for help

Comment: Have you check the answer to this question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/304782/how-to-add-fonts-in-libreoffice-writer

Comment: What version of Lubuntu are you using?

Comment: its version 12.04

Answer (score 1):

#### *Note: These screenshots are outdated and need to be updated. I don't have lubuntu and can't get access to it. If anyone would like to take updated screenshots and edit them into this post, that would be greatly appreciated. Until then (if it happens), the screenshots will stay as 10.04 ones.*

## Adding a keyboard language

1. Navigate to **System** → **Preferences** → **Keyboard**.
   [image: screenshot]
2. In the Keyboard Preferences dialog, select the **Layouts** tab, and click **Add**.
   [image: screenshot2]
3. You can select a country and then choose an language and keyboard variant.  Note that some countries, such as the United States, may show several languages.  Once you’ve made your selection, you can preview it on the sample keyboard displayed below the menu.
   [image: screenshot3]
   Alternately, on the second tab, select a language and then choose a variant.  Click **Add** when you’ve made your selection.
   [image: screenshot4]
4. Now you’ll notice that there are two languages listed in the Keyboard Preferences, and they’re both ready to use immediately.  You can add more if you wish, or close the dialog.
   [image: screenshot5]

## Switching between languages

### Manually

1. When you have multiple input languages installed, you’ll notice a new icon in your system tray on the top right. It will show the abbreviation of the country and/or language name that is currently selected. Click the icon to change the language.
   [image: screenshot6]
2. Right-click the dialog to view available languages (listed under **Groups**), open the Keyboard Preferences dialog again, or show the current layout.
   [image: screenshot7]
3. If you select **Show Current Layout** you’ll see a window with the keyboard preview we saw previously when setting the keyboard layout.  You can even print this layout preview out to help you remember a layout if you wish.
   [image: screenshot8]

### Shortcuts

1. By default, you can switch input languages in Ubuntu from the keyboard by pressing both <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys together.  Many users are already used to the default <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Switch combination to switch input languages in Windows, and we can add that in Ubuntu.  Open the keyboard preferences dialog, select the **Layout** tab, and click **Options**.
   [image: screenshot9]
2. Click the plus sign beside **Key(s) to change layout**, and select <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. Click **Close**, and you can now use this familiar shortcut to switch input languages.
   [image: screenshot10]

#### *Extra Option* - LED Indicator

If your keyboard supports LED indicators, then you can add this feature to notify you when you're using a different input method.

The layout options dialog offers many more neat keyboard shortcuts and options. One especially neat option was the option to use a keyboard LED to show when we’re using the alternate keyboard layout. I selected the ScrollLock light since it’s hardly used today, and now it lights up when we’re using our other input language.
[image: screenshot11]

## Credits

All credit goes to [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/)

Comment: Those screenshots seem to be from 10.04, and the UI has changed significantly since then - you might want to take new screenshots.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the suggestion. Might take a bit to get some updated screenshots from my machine, but I will add them as soon as I can. Is the navigation for Lubuntu the same for regular Ubuntu or at least relatively similar? My machine is running 14.04 Unity so that's what I have access to for screenshots. If not, then I can try and find some updated screenshots online or if I need to, install a Virtual Machine of Lubuntu on my home computer.

Comment: doing the way you just showed is the mere translation of english typed words into another language. I need the actual typing of another language not the translation of english typed words into another language

Comment: @Ashim given some Nepalese word, what do you want to type to get it?

Comment: For example if I want to type my name in Nepali , following the way you showed compels me to type my name according to English keyboard and it translates to Nepali but with Nepali grammar error. Instead I want to type Nepali in the standard Nepali keyboard layout and not the Nepali in english layout which is mere conversion into Nepali language with grammatical errors